# iPhone:How to post image to flickr from ios 4 and greater versions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flickr

I want to send image to flickr from my application for that

I have done a lot of search and also google but I couldn't find the solution

so if you have any idea then share it

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.
If you want something else, please let me know\

http://macapper.com/2007/07/28/tutorial-how-to-make-a-flickr-uploader-plug-in-part-1/

or this:

http://objective-c.wonderhowto.com/how-to/upload-image-website-from-apple-ios-application-333979/